# Want to read complete content of text file which has a max of 1MB size

Tags: java

in JAVA i want to read the complete content of .log file which has a max of 1MB size and i need to store it in StringBuilder

I tried using this code, but giving exception STACKERRORFLOW.

```
            String fileName = "C://test//.log";
    File testfile = new File(fileName);
    int ch;
    StringBuilder strcontent = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(testfile);
        while((ch = fis.read()) != -1)
            strcontent.append((char)ch);
        fis.close();        
    }
            System.out.println(strcontent.toString());
```

What will be the problem in it.

Comment: Your code seems incomplete. Where is your catch block.

Comment: On which line is the `Exception` being thrown?

Comment: Start by specifing the expected content size of the `StringBuilder`, something like `1024*1024`, this will preallocate the internal buffer so it won't need to be resized on the run.  Read in an array of bytes as chunks.  You could even use a `FileReader` which would allow you use a `char` array

Comment: StringBuilder shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read log file i suggest you to use [`java.io.BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

```
BufferedReader r = null;
File testfile = new File("C://test//.log");
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(testfile));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            b.append(line);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
       try {
          r.close()
       }
       catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

**Stackoverflow** can cause as @MadProgrammer pointed out.

And also you are reading bigger file char by char that is i think not effective. Do you know how much times will be `append()` method called?

As @joan pointed out -Xmx JVM option this i think won't help because this is related to problem of heap size and not stackoverflow. SO is usually thrown when you are doing big recursions or generally if something is called a lot of times and variables fill up stack.

Comment: Then, close `r` in a `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the maximum heap size.

Use the -Xmx JVM option to increase the Java maximum heap size. Hope this helps.

Comment: If the issue was the Heap Size wouldn't the problem be a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` rather than a stack overflow?

Comment: Thanks all for your reply.. :) It helped me a lot. :)